# Calculating distance between plaintext and ciphertext of a Caesar cipher

Tags: java, encryption, caesar-cipher

I have a text file like this:

```
GASDGHSDH BVNYBCNYC
HDFS UQSF
CXVN KFDV
SHDF APLN
HDSFHS OKZMOZ
SAH YGN
DSHF HWLJ
REEW TGGY
SGDFH AOLNP
DHSF EITG
GSDHASD IUFJCUF
DHFSDF KOMZKM
DSFH SHUW
```

And I don't know decryption key. For Example:
HDFS UQSF
Key == 13

because  U - H == 13

Ok. I write code:

```
public static int codeJC(String first, String twice){
    first = first.toLowerCase();
    twice = twice.toLowerCase();
    char a = first.charAt(0);
    char b = twice.charAt(0);


    int r = 0;
    if((a-b) >0){
        r = a-b;
    }else{
        r = b-a;

    }

    return r;


}
```

But if:

```
System.out.println(codeJC("Z", "A")); //this return 25 !?!?!?!?
System.out.println(codeJC("C", "F")); //this return good value
```

Why when a < b gets a bad value?

Comment: S, H and D are your most common letters; one of those is probably an E in the plain text (assuming it is in English).

Comment: Well, that's what you've written in the code, but what did you expect? Did you expect `1`?

Comment: Text each time it is different because they get it in a file and I need to decrypt.I count this key but do not know how.

Comment: `'z'` has ASCII-Value 122, `'a'` has 97. Since you calculate `'z'-'a'` (122-97), 25 is exactly what sould be the result, according to your code. What did you think that the value should be?

Comment: So if one text is "ZZZZ" A second " AAAAA " It expects 1

Comment: Okay I understand this mistake of his idea . But how do I do that?

Comment: You could use `r = 26 - (b-a);`, but I'm still wondering what this will give you in regards of finding the correct key.

Comment: Almost but otherwise , but thanks for the help :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
if ((a - b) > 0) {
    r = 26 - (a - b);
} else {
    r = b - a;
}
```

Comment: while this may provide the proper solution it would be nice if you could explain why and how you use this snippet!

Comment: Why it works, I do not know, but to work just paste the code that was in question

Comment: why do you add 26 before you subtract?